# DockPanels in C# - Layering Possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, dockpanel

I'm a little new to `C#` and `WPF`, so forgive me if this is an uninformed question. I'd like to know if it is possible to layer something on top of a region of a `dockPanel`. So, for example, say I have something like:

```
<theme:obligatory DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
             x:Name="name" ClipToBounds="False" 
             SnapsToDevicePixels="False" />
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to layer something on top of this region, either within the same .xaml or via a different class. I'd like to layer text, if that makes any difference.

Thanks!

Comment: Please define "layer on top off".

Comment: Note sure what you mean by, "either within the same .xaml or via a different class," since these two things aren't mutually exclusive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF, all XAML defined lower in the page will be rendered on top of the controls that are defined higher in the page. So to overlay anything, just declare it at the bottom of your page. Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel />
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Margin="250,100,50,200" />
</Grid>
```

In this example, the `Rectangle` will appear to float above the `DockPanel`. Adjust the `Margin` to place it wherever you want.

Comment: If this answer has helped you to solve your problem, then please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), as is customary on this website

Comment: ^I know, I'm just not logged in to my usual account. Was just busy.

Comment: Good for you... unfortunately, not all users take the time to read through the various pages of the Help Centre.